# how to write custom linear collection in scala

Tags: scala, collections

I'd like to write custom linear collection. Something like extended List in some specific cases (not for all parameter types).

Scala has complicated collection class hierarchy and I'm lost. What trait should I extend, what methods should I implement?

I've found comprehended tutorial for *custom traversable* implementation: http://daily-scala.blogspot.ru/2010/04/creating-custom-traversable.html.

And I'm searching for similar hints about implementing custom linear sequence.

Comment: just adding info for other readers: scala collection guide: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/introduction.html and scala collections api: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really isn't that different from implementing a traverasable. There are only two abstract method on `LinearSeq`, and three on `LinearSeqLike`, which you should also extend.

However, as the doc for the latter makes clear, it is important that you override the following methods so they have an efficient implementation:

```
 def isEmpty: Boolean
 def head: A
 def tail: Repr
```